# How do I use the notification light as a one time notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have an application that needs debugging while the display is off. Is there a way to use the notification light to show individual interrupts?

I'm measuring GPS changes and was hoping to flash the light every GPS change (~1 sec).

Can I get it to flash that frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(iconId, text, when);
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notification.ledOnMS = 1000;
notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
```

Note, some devices require screen to be off for LED notification to show up.

Comment: Does this code mean the light will not come on for 1 second and then off after one second.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Create a notification with flag FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS

notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;

And then every second update your notification and change notification led color.